# PDO insert 4 times at once

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, phpmyadmin

when I try to run this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=lior;charset=utf-8' ,'root', '');
$pdo->exec("INSERT INTO  `users` (
`username` ,
`email`
)
VALUES (
'lior',  'lior'
);");
```

it inserts the row "lior,lior" **4 times.**

when I try to run it on my phpmyadmin it inserts the row once.

thank you.

Comment: Your code is either in a loop, or it is in a function which gets called multiple times

Answer (score 1):

This code being called four times.

It's quite unusual though - 2 times is more familiar to me. 
Nevertheless, you need to verify your browser and your server.

Try Firefox with LiveHTTPHeaders addon, and watch how many HTTP requests browser does

Comment: I replaced this code with "echo 'hey';" and I saw only one "hey".

Comment: Check your access log. You probably have more than one request being made.